# Can't get margin to align correctly FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

having some problems when I output to PDF. The idea is to have a banner image that spans the full width of the A4 document. then underneath I have a form, but it keeps aligning to the very left of the page. I'd like to have some margin set. Here is what I have so far:

```
$pdf = new PDF();
    $pdf->SetMargins(1,1,1);
    $pdf->SetXY(-1,-1);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
    //Insert Banner
    $pdf->Image('../assets/pdfBanner.png');
    $pdf->Ln();

    //Insert Indemnity form
    $text=$pdf->WriteHTML($indemRow['form']);
    $nb=$pdf->WordWrap($text,120);
    $pdf->MultiCell(300, 10, $pdf->Write(500,$text));
    $pdf->Ln();

    //Insert Signature
    $x = $pdf->GetX();
    $y = $pdf->GetY();
    $pdf->MultiCell(30, 10, $pdf->WriteHTML('<u>Signature         </ul>'));
    $pdf->SetXY($x + 30, $y);

    $pdf->MultiCell(63, 10, $pdf->Image('signature1.png'));
    $pdf->Ln(0);

    $pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'D');
```

My problem is the few lines under //Insert Indemnity form. I want some margin, I thought using `SetMarginLeft();` would do i, but it doesn't. please help!

Answer (score 0):

Just before outputting the form you must set x to an appropriate value.

```
$pdf->setX(20);
```

Alternatively you can set margins before outputting anyone. But I am not 100% sure how this will work with a full width banner.

Comment: Hey thanks for your input. Yeah I tried that and had no luck, I tried setting X before my indemnity for and before the output, but the form is still aligned to the far left. I thought I could use multiCells to achieve this, have one empty cell, then another one with the form, and a third one on the right for right margin.

Comment: MMh, and why do you use
    $pdf->MultiCell(300, 10, $pdf->Write(500,$text));
instead of
    $pdf->MultiCell(300, 10, $indemRow['form']);

Comment: the contents of $indemRow['form'] are HTML which needed to be converted first!

Comment: and have you tried something like  $pdf->setMargins(20, 20, 20);

Comment: Yeah I tried that also but then the banner image doesn't sit at the very top left of the page

Comment: and what is the content of $indemRow['form'];

Comment: Here is a snippet of the contents after it has been formatted:

 TEST 4 If you agree to these terms and conditions continue to the next page TO
THE CUSTOMER: By taking part in any of the activities we offer you are assuming a degree of risk. Please
read the following carefully & do not sign it if you do not understand it or do not agree with its terms.      
 Ocean Rafting Customer's Indemnity & Release Form

Comment: and you convert the text twice, have you tried inserting $text in the multicell

Comment: Yes, I had to convert twice, one to convert to HTML, and another time so it wraps. I have tried inserting $text and still no go unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in the fpdf.php source file. Don´t be afraid to fix it yourself! Open the fpdf.php file, look for the SetMargins() implementation, and right below of this function you will find the implementation of SetLeftMargin(), wich works fine. You will find in the latter function a couple lines of code that checks and sets a private variable 'x'. These instructions are not in the SetMargins() implementation, and are the most likely cause of the problem. Just copy and adapt those lines at the end of the SetMargins() function. Here's my fix:

```
if($this->page > 0 && $this->x < $left)
    $this->x = $left;
```

Just copy those lines inside SetMargins(), at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that the margins you set only are one mm in size

`$pdf = new PDF();`
    `$pdf->SetMargins(1,1,1);`
    `$pdf->SetXY(-1,-1);`
    `$pdf->AddPage();`

Also; I don't know how fpdf use the margins and SetXY, but If you have set the margins of a page, and add a page, the X and Y variables should automatically be reset to the actual top and left margins, so the page should be set before moving the XY. If my memory serves, then the XY is related to the actual position on the page, so if you want them in the top left corner (without margins), it should be 0,0.